React Native Android Development, Very Slow Build time
I'm using an 8GB RAM i3 11th gen Laptop, react-native 0.76.1. Whenever I use npx react-native run-android it takes almost 10-15 minutes to run, even when I connected a physical device with my laptop via OTG.
I used npx react-native run-android --active-arch-only, but still it takes 5 minutes to start, see below:

And my application is just initialized, no extra packages, no expo router, it's pure react native cli project.
I tried with npx react-native start via the metro bundler directly, but still that takes a lot of time.
